# How to trigger constraint updates on UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uikit

I have a collectionView and I add (programatically) a view to contentView of the cell in the cellForItem... 
Then i resize the view so that its frame equals contentView's bounds. contentView has correct size and the view gets correct one but it does not refresh it's constraints. How to refresh them? I tried setNeedsLayout and stuff, it just doesn't work. Constraints are 100% OK.

Comment: Have you tried to call "updateConstraints" on your view? Or "updateConstraintsIfNeeded".

Comment: Those methods change constraints (see Apple docs). I do not want to change them. I want the view's layout updated according to existing, unmodified constraints.

Comment: Can you show/explain the contraints you have in your cell and what is the result you want after adding the view to the contentView ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to call `[view layoutIfNeeded]`, this explicitly ask to refresh the constraints

Comment: I called it, but it seems that the constraint calculations somehow ignore new bounds of the view. Could this be?

Comment: Have you set this? translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;